# Testing RAM from a dead computer

Tags: memory, hardware-failure

I have a Mac Mini, which died due to motherboard and power supply failure. I'd like to know if it is safe to take out the RAM module and check it in another computer too see if it is working. If the RAM module is bad, do I risk breaking the computer I want to test it in?

Comment: I've seen motherboards kill ram, but never the other way around.

Comment: Duplicate: [Is it dangerous to insert (potentially) burnt RAM into a motherboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/676263/is-it-dangerous-to-insert-potentially-burnt-ram-into-a-motherboard)

Answer (score 0):

You can safely test the RAM in another Mac by running the [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/HT201257) [AHT] at boot.

The method is different depending on how old your Mac is. Up to about 2012, you hold  <kbd>D</kbd>   at the chimes, which will load the test from disk. 2012 onwards, hold  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>D</kbd>   which will download the test from the internet. Newer still & instead of the Hardware Test you will get Apple Diagnostics.

Hold your key combo at the chimes & wait until the very 1980's-looking screen comes up.
Wait for the initial tests to finish, then check the "Perform extended testing" box & run the tests.

Note that this can take a **long time**. [Estimate 1hr per GB RAM being tested]

The progress screen is not very informative, but if you can still move the cursor, it's still working.

After the tests have completed, it will either tell you all is well, or provide an error code, which you can look up on this TechRepublic page - [How to decipher error codes in Apple Hardware Test or Apple Diagnostics](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-decipher-error-codes-in-apple-hardware-test-or-apple-diagnostics/)
Memory error codes would begin with 4MEM.

If you cannot get the AHT to load, it's possible to boot most Macs from a USB holding the specific AHT for that model.
A method to make the USB key & a comprehensive list of downloadable model-specific AHT versions is held at https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest

Answer (score -1):

It'll be fine. The BIOS will check the ram is generally working ok when you boot and if the ram is damaged will either ignore it or tell you about it.

If the computer boots, then check how much ram it thinks it has to see if the new stuff is registering ok. Maybe use [Memtest](http://www.memtest.org/) or [Windows Memory Diagnostic](https://www.howtogeek.com/260813/how-to-test-your-computers-ram-for-problems/) to test for less obvious problems.

Comment: BIOS? Windows? ...

Comment: You said 'test in another computer'. As there are so many Windows computers around, more than Mac or Linux, it's reasonable to assume you might use one for testing.